# Mobile menu dropdown pushes down main content

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, dropdown, responsive

i am using a simple responsive dropdown menu with a little jquery. the code itself works properly. but when i add it to the page content, it pushes down the main content when in mobile view. in desktop view the dropdown appears "over" the main content as it should. 
i tried to give the ul li a position:relative; as i read in some advices, but that doesnt work either. is the problem maybe the jquery code? 
i am also using some flexbox design, but i dont thing this is the problem?

the HTML structure:

```
    <body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="full-width flex-container">
        <div class="logo-wrap">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" id="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-wrap">
            <nav>
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><b>Item1</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b>Item2</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b>Item3</b></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="active">Sub-Item3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b>Item4</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b>Item5</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="wrap">
            <article>
                <h1>Bilanz</h1>
                <hr id="top-hr">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua...............</p>

    </article>
    </div>
     </main>
</div>
```

the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.full-width {
    position: relative;
    /* child absolute */
    margin: 0 -9999rem;
    /* add back section padding value */
    padding: .25rem 9999rem;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav-wrap {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
.main-wrap {
    display: flex;
}
header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#logo {
    max-width: 100%;
}
main {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
article {
    margin-top: 3em;
    padding: 2em;
}
aside {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
h1 {
    color: #97C227;
}
h1,
h2,
p {
    padding: 0.8em 0;
}
#top-hr {
    height: 4px;
    color: #d9d9d9;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    border-style: none;
}
/*###############-------navigation-------############*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul li a:hover {
    color: #97C227;
}
ul li a.active {
    color: #97C227;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 200px;
    background: lightgrey;
    display: none;
}
ul ul li {
    display: block;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
nav div {
    background-color: pink;
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0.6em;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
/*###########   media queries   ##############*/
@media(max-width: 768px) {
    nav div {
        display: block;
    }
    ul {
        display: none;
        position: static;
        background: #e3e3e3;
    }
    ul li {
        display: block;
    }
    ul ul {
        position: static;
        background: #e3e3e3;
    }
}
```

the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("nav div").click(function() {
    $("ul").slideToggle();
    $("ul ul").css("display", "none");
});

$("ul li").click(function() {
    $("ul ul").slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $("ul").removeAttr('style')
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please make your code shorter and to the point. It seems as if you have uploaded all of your code.

Comment: What happens when you make the `position` as `relative`? There are two ways to find out this, one is you tell me or the other is I have execute the code myself, but your code is very long and not to the point, so please attach a fiddle or any platform where I can monitor and check your result and outcomes.

Comment: @Code_Ninja sorry for the amount of code, as i am a very beginner i thought it helps to see the whole thing. i will try your advice

Comment: its okay @lalofee , just edit the question again and make it to the point.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lalofee/09g9pa6e/  put it on fiddle,

Comment: sorry, made a mistake, use this link instead: https://jsfiddle.net/lalofee/r17mm4kk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use position absolute on your dropdown in order for it to disregard the other page elements.

Your media queries change the position of some elements to static - if it is working ok on desktop before you add that rule then try removing that line of css

Comment: you mean the"second" ul? in css, the ul ul hast the attribute absolute; removing  the "static" attributes doesnt help

Comment: no change the first ul to position absolute with your media query -

Comment: this will make the dropdown content sit over your other page content